# .net XmlSerialize, ignore class properties

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Assuming we have two classes Apple, Pineapple

```
public class Apple:Fruit{}
public class Pineapple:Fruit{}
```

And we have an abstract class named Fruit

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Apple))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Pineapple))]
public abstract class Fruit{}
```

And we have a class named Menu

```
public class Menu 
{
    [XmlElement("apple",typeof(Apple))]
    [XmlElement("",typeof(Pineapple))]
    public Fruit fruit {get;set;}
}
```

I'd like to ignore the fruit property  when the type is Pineapple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to do that, but you can use the `ShouldSerialize<PropertyName>` pattern to achieve it:

```
public class Menu 
{
    [XmlElement("apple",typeof(Apple))]
    public Fruit fruit {get;set;}

    public bool ShouldSerializefruit()
    {
        return !(fruit is Pineapple);
    }

}
```

Comment: I need to produce clean xml outpot, and one of the fruits actually represents "no fruit". Thanks it worked!